# Access Denied when accessing website using python selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I want to create a simple automation using python selenium, but it is said that Access Denied, I'm running on ubuntu 20.04, in google cloud, running in headless mode, anyone knows how to solve this?

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.517 Safari/5>
chrome_options.add_argument('user-agent={0}'.format(user_agent))
chrome_options.headless = True


browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = "/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver",chrome_options=chrome_option>

browser.get("https://www.chegg.com/auth?action=login&redirect=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.chegg.com%2F")
print(browser.title)
```